# Event 1000, Application Error, Windows 7, Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, event-log

I've got an application we use at our company.

All of our Windows XP PCs and Windows 7 PCs use it.

I can run it in the debugger under Visual Studio 2008 and build the Installer that all of the other PCs use to install it with, but I can not get it to run after installing on my PC (the installation shows no errors).

Under Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application, two (2) events are fired:

1. The Error thrown when I try to run the installed application:

   > Faulting application name: Suite.exe, version: 2.2.21.0, time stamp: 0x4d389f32
   >   Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16559, time stamp: 0x4ba9b802
   >   Exception code: 0xc00000fd
   >   Fault offset: 0x00000000000076cf
   >   Faulting process id: 0x1424
   >   Faulting application start time: 0x01cbb8f485a2a9d8
   >   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Aaon Coil Products, Inc\ACP Software Suite\Suite.exe
   >   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
   >   Report Id: c58bd590-24e7-11e0-b398-00248103a942
2. An Informational message fires up immediately after with Windows Error Reporting:

   > Fault bucket 28268826, type 4
   >   Event Name: APPCRASH
   >   Response: Not available
   >   Cab Id: 0
   >
   > Problem signature:
   >   P1: Suite.exe
   >   P2: 2.2.21.0
   >   P3: 4d389f32
   >   P4: ntdll.dll
   >   P5: 6.1.7600.16559
   >   P6: 4ba9b802
   >   P7: c00000fd
   >   P8: 00000000000076cf
   >   P9:
   >   P10:
   >
   > Attached files:
   >   C:\Users\cp-jpool\AppData\Local\Temp\WER492A.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
   >
   > These files may be available here:
   >   C:\Users\cp-jpool\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_Suite.exe_e131a0d577e0788f7db9b54fd53b35e27d8860e2_11df4dea
   >
   > Analysis symbol:
   >   Rechecking for solution: 0
   >   Report Id: c58bd590-24e7-11e0-b398-00248103a942
   >   Report Status: 0

This repeats every time I try to run the application I made with this PC ...on this PC, but no where else.

Could someone give me some idea of what's going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my application uses a control that does not run on 64-bit environments.

Apparently, the debugger in VS2008 will not throw an error whenever one of these old style DLLs fails.

Answer (score 1):

Do you get prompted to elevate Visual Studio when you run it?

If so, try running the app elevated.

Basically, isolate what's different between the two:

1. Can you run it in Visual Studio *without* debugging? Including when you set it to "Release"?
2. How about if you build and install it as "Debug" then start it and try to attach to it as it crashes? (You can set the JIT debugger via the registry here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx)

Good luck!

Comment: No error message is displayed when the program is run on my PC, so no prompt to elevate Visual Studio.

Comment: In Release mode, Any CPU: The application runs from the debugger. The Start Without Debugging (CTRL+F5) option shows the Cursor.AppStarting for a few seconds, but the application never starts or throws an error.

Comment: In Debug mode, Any CPU: I built the application and the Setup project and installed it. Running the installed application does the same as Release mode without Debugging: The Curser.AppStarting cursor shows for a few seconds, but the application never starts or throws an error.

Comment: The only place I have been able to trace down errors is in the Event Viewer console.

Comment: Did you try running it elevated as well? Also, how about creating a new user account local to the machine. Make it a member of the local administrators group. Log off of the machine, then log in as the new user - try running the program as that user. (Still trying to isolate just what's different.)

Comment: Elevated? I don't understand this.

Comment: Starting with Windows Vista, by default you don't run with administrative rights automatically unless you are logged in as the user named "administrator". If you're a member of the local "administrators" group then you _can_ run things with full permissions, but you must choose to do it. If you aren't a member of that group and try to run something with full permissions ("elevated permissions") then you'll be prompted to enter the user name and password of an account that does have those rights. This causes no end of 'fun' when troubleshooting. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control